# Unexpected token when reading bytes: String

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, byte

This the JSON response from the API:

```
{
  "order_id": 1020304051,
  "order_number": "10001",
  "carrier_name": "Australia Post",
  "tracking_numbers": [
    "QQQ001156301000960302"
  ],
  "labels": [
    "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"
  ],
  "label_types": [
    "AusPost"
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

I have this class to convert the data:

```
public class LabelResult
{
    public long order_id { get; set; }
    public string order_number { get; set; }
    public string carrier_name { get; set; }
    public Array tracking_numbers { get; set; }
    public byte[] labels { get; set; }
    //public Array label_types { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the codes for converting of `httpresponse`:

```
private LabelResult ConvertLabelResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var label_response = new LabelResult();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        jsonString.Wait();
        if (jsonString.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = JObject.Parse(jsonString.Result);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelResult>(data.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return label_response;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have these errors:

> 1. Unexpected token when reading bytes: String. Path 'labels[0]', line 18, position 10482.
> 2. Could not create an instance of type System.Array. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path
>      'tracking_numbers', line 5, position 23.

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Use `IEnumerable<string> tracking_numbers`

Comment: How about the labels error?

Comment: Same thing - `IEnumerable<string> labels` (ditto for `label_types`)

Comment: Isnt it labels a byte array ?

Comment: Does not look like it in the json you have shown

Comment: I have updated to the actual response

Comment: Looks like it should be `public byte[][] labels` and `public string [] tracking_numbers { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your root model should be:

```
public class LabelResult
{
    public long order_id { get; set; }
    public string order_number { get; set; }
    public string carrier_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> tracking_numbers { get; set; }
    public List<byte []> labels { get; set; }
    public List<string> label_types { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- As shown in its [serialization guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm), Json.NET will map a Base64-encoded string to a `byte []`.  Your `"labels"` property is an array of such strings, so should be bound to a `byte [][]` or `List<byte []>`.
- There is no reason to parse to a `JObject` then convert back to a string to deserialize:

  ```
  var data = JObject.Parse(jsonString.Result);
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelResult>(data.ToString());
  ```

  Instead deserialize from the result:

  ```
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelResult>(jsonString.Result);
  ```
- Always prefer using typed collections such as `List<string>` to untyped collections such as [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) or `Array`.  Furthermore [`System.Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) is an abstract base type so cannot be instantiated directly.
- You could use arrays instead of lists if you prefer:

  ```
  public string [] tracking_numbers { get; set; }
  public byte [][] labels { get; set; }
  public string [] label_types { get; set; }
  ```

  I find resizable collections to be more convenient, and so prefer `List<T>`.

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SET43h).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is your are initializing array with Array keyword. This might be wrong.
**tracking_numbers** might be array of string.
Secondly, When you read Json data, you have to manually cast your labels is also array which is not matched

```
"Label": ["..."]
```

If you want to read, you have to cast manually or 2D Array on initialization.

```
public byte[][] labels { get; set; }
```